# Firebase phone OTP verification in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, verification, one-time-password

> I am trying to verify a phone number using firebase phone number authentication. I have 3 activities. First one is "**EnterMobile**", second one is "**OtpVerification**" and last one is "**dashboard**". I am able to send **OTP** but when I enter OTP and click on verify button, it goes back to first activity instead of dashboard activity.

```
public class OtpVerification extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText inputotp1, inputotp2, inputotp3, inputotp4, inputotp5, inputotp6;
    private String getotpbackend;
    public OtpVerification() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_otp_verification);
        inputotp1 = findViewById(R.id.inputotp1);
        inputotp2 = findViewById(R.id.inputotp2);
        inputotp3 = findViewById(R.id.inputotp3);
        inputotp4 = findViewById(R.id.inputotp4);
        inputotp5 = findViewById(R.id.inputotp5);
        inputotp6 = findViewById(R.id.inputotp6);
        getotpbackend = getIntent().getStringExtra("backendOtp");
        final ProgressBar progressBarSendOtp = findViewById(R.id.sending_otp_progress_bar);
        final Button submitOtp = findViewById(R.id.submitOtp);
        TextView ShowMobile = findViewById(R.id.ShowMobile);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        ShowMobile.setText(String.format(
                "+971-%s", intent.getStringExtra("mobile")
        ));



        submitOtp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!inputotp1.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() && !inputotp2.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() && !inputotp3.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() && !inputotp4.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() && !inputotp5.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() && !inputotp6.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                    String entercodeotp = inputotp1.getText().toString() +
                            inputotp2.getText().toString() +
                            inputotp3.getText().toString() +
                            inputotp4.getText().toString() +
                            inputotp5.getText().toString() +
                            inputotp6.getText().toString();
                    if (getotpbackend != null) {
                        progressBarSendOtp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        submitOtp.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
                                getotpbackend, entercodeotp
                        );
                        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential)
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull  Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                        progressBarSendOtp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        submitOtp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), dashboard.class);
                                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                            startActivity(intent);
                                        } else {
                                            Toast.makeText(OtpVerification.this, "Enter Correct OTP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(OtpVerification.this, "Please Check Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    //   Toast.makeText(OtpVerification.this, "otp verify", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(OtpVerification.this, "Please enter all OTP number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        numberOtpMove();
        TextView ResendLabel = findViewById(R.id.SendAgain);
        ResendLabel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                        "+971" + getIntent().getStringExtra("mobile"),
                        60,
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                        OtpVerification.this,
                        new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
                            @Override
                            public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull  PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), dashboard.class);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull @NotNull FirebaseException e) {

                                Toast.makeText(OtpVerification.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCodeSent(@NonNull @NotNull String newbackendotp, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                                super.onCodeSent(newbackendotp, forceResendingToken);
                                getotpbackend = newbackendotp;
                                Toast.makeText(OtpVerification.this, "OTP Sent Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                );
            }
        });
    }

    private void numberOtpMove() {

        inputotp1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (!s.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                    inputotp2.requestFocus();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
        inputotp2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (!s.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                    inputotp3.requestFocus();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
        inputotp3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (!s.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                    inputotp4.requestFocus();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
        inputotp4.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (!s.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                    inputotp5.requestFocus();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
        inputotp5.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (!s.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                    inputotp6.requestFocus();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```